# How to change keyboard layout in tty2?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, tty

I have faced the problem - I can't connect to tty2 as I can't enter valid login and password because I can't change keyboard layout which is Russian by default. I go to tty2 by pressing fn + ctrl + alt + f2 when booting Ubuntu. My login and password are written in English but I can print only Russian. I tried a lot of shortcuts to change the keyboard layot but it was useless. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the order of the layouts in the `/etc/default/keyboard` file, so `us` is placed first in the list. It can be done from *Settings -> Region & Language* when you are logged in into a usual session.